# how can we manage multiple request in ESB

Tags: wso2, esb

How the ESB will handle multiple request for example 1000 request.
If suppose UI part will give you 1000 request then how the esb will handle these request.
Anyone help me out ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can get idea on how ESB handles request and performance figures from below links.

http://wso2.com/library/articles/2012/03/importance-performance-wso2-esb-handles-nonobvious/

http://wso2.com/library/articles/2013/01/esb-performance-65/